# Changing "active content" security settings on WPF WebBrowser control

Tags: wpf, activex, wpf-controls

I'm putting together a WPF application that will allow users to view PowerPoint files through the WebBrowser control, once the files have been saved as either .MHT or .HTML. The problem is that the files contain ActiveX controls, and the WebBrowser control by default will display a warning every time I load these files, saying "To help protect your security, your web browser has restricted this file from showing active content that could access your computer."

I've seen a few different places online talk about putting [the mark of the web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(VS.85).aspx) into each page, but that really doesn't work for me in this case, since the content authors have control over the files, not the developers, and I'd rather not tell them that they have to open every single file in Notepad and add the mark of the web to each one.

Is there any way to just change the WebBrowser control's settings to not display that warning message? IE has a similar setting, but it doesn't carry over into this control.

Answer (score 17):

We eventually found a decent solution to this, although I still wish there were some sort of settings on the control itself. To load the documents, we just set `browser.Source` to be the following:

file://127.0.0.1/c$/path/to/the/file (where the path is an absolute path without C:\, for example, c$/Users/jschuster/mydocument.html)

For whatever reason, the control will display files referenced by a URL in that format without a warning.

Comment: Wow... I love the so-called security of Internet Explorer, it's so easily tricked ;)

Comment: Neither of these workarounds seem to work for me. Maybe it's windows 7 :(

Comment: This worked for me, but on the first pageload after the application launched there would often be a significant lag.

Comment: Does the 'c' in "c$" represents the C: drive? So if the HTML file is in D: drive, it would be d$ ?

Answer (score 15):

Hope this might help someone even that the question is a bit old ...

As per the link to ["The Mark Of The Web"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28VS.85%29.aspx) , adding comment like

```
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
```

just under the HTML tag worked.

My index.html is in HTML folder, added as "content" set to "Always copy" in WPF project using WebBrowser control.
The address to the file during execution look like this:

```
file:///E:/SRC_2013/WebBrowserTestApp/WebBrowserTestApp/bin/Debug/HTML/index.html
```

Comment: Never too old to post a suggested answer to legacy IE support! :)

Comment: Setting js and css files to "Always copy" inside a Visual Studio .sln worked for me...finally.

Comment: I confirm that **it works on Windows 10 with WebBrowser control** loading HTML page which hosts Flash object. Solution with IP address and private share didn't work, though - main Flash movie was loaded but it failed to dynamically load content from ActionScript.

Answer (score 2):

Why not insert the MOTW dynamically at the beginning of the file when you load it ?

By the way, thanks for your question : I didn't know about the "mark of the web" and it solved a problem I had :)

Comment: Mostly because it adds a lot more work to our end, especially finding the end of the DOCTYPE declaration. I'm probably imagining it to be more work than it is, but right now we're just setting browser.Source to essentially a modified file path, so actually loading and parsing the file adds a bit more effort.

Plus, it just seems like the WebBrowser control should have some sort of settings for this, in case the default security settings don't meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

file://127.0.0.1/c$/path/to/the/file (where the path is an absolute path without C:\, for example, c$/Users/jschuster/mydocument.html)

This worked for me as well on Win7.

Answer (score 0):

the solution from [here](https://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/840/working-with-webbrowser-in-wpf) worked for me on windows 11

the solution is to put the line below at the beginning of the html file you want to load:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```