# WPF WebBrowser Control and security message

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I use the WPF WebBrowser as follow. When I use this in a new autonom Application, I became the following message at top of the browser:
[image]

on english:

showing active content that access to the computer has restricted this file for security reasons. Click here for more options ...

When I use the same code in a existing application on the same machine (the exactly same code - as a seperate window), the Message is not shown. 
Does someone can help me, why this message is not shown when I use the webbrowser-Control (copied the code) in an existing application? - Thanks.

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var path = @"C:\temp\WpfApplication1\MHTBody_5f9d8e2b-9dee-42a6-959c-0edfc43b5daf.proconactNavigating.mht";
        this.webBrowser.Navigate(path);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1674.761" Width="900.637">
    <Grid>
        <Button Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click_1" />
        <WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Margin="0,31,0,0" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**New Informations:**

When I add in the sample-Application (in the new autonom application), where the MainWindow is in and the securitybar is shown Settings to the application and access this, before I open the MainWindow, the securitybar will not be shown anymore and it will take long more time to load the mht.

Concret:

When I dot this, it will not show the securitybar:

```
public partial class App : Application {
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
        var x = Settings.Default.test;
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you face any problem at runtime or this is just at design time?

Comment: These links might be of your use - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940435/changing-active-content-security-settings-on-wpf-webbrowser-control
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/f73bb9fa-3252-4c7e-b8e4-6cdad59fd825

Comment: @RV1987 - I don't think, this links are helping me. I want to show the security bar in my existing application - not "not to show". I am confused, why it works in a new application but not when I use the same in my exisiting application (on the same machine).

Comment: I have seen know, that, when I show a Form in a WebBrowser and navigate to my mht-File before I access the Settings (Settings.Default) it will show the yellow security-warning bar. When I access the Settings and show it after, it will not show the securitybar anymore and it will take a long time to load.