# How to load HTML via WPF WebBrowser without security message

Tags: javascript, c#, html, wpf

I'm working on a WPF application in which i generate the content of a HTML-file as a string (including some JavaScrip functions for calculation).
Then i write that string as HTML-file to my local disc and reload it with the WPF WebBrowser control.
The loading works but i get always a message bar at the top of the WebBrowser control that some contents are blocked because of security problems.

I had the same problem when i was experitmenting with an existing HTML-file, but could solve these problems by adding some DWORD-entries to the registry ([example on this site](https://codevomit.wordpress.com/2015/06/12/wpf-webbrowser-control-part-1/)) and the following line at the beginning of the HTML-file:

```
<!--saved from url=(0014)about:internet-->
```

I tried that one instead but the result is the same:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
```

Are there any further settings i have to change?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940435/changing-active-content-security-settings-on-wpf-webbrowser-control/27917886#27917886

Comment: Hi vidriduch! As i wrote above, i tried the localhost variant and it doesn't work. The result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!
The file was - more or less - correct but i have made two mistakes.
First there have to be spaces in the first line of the HTML file.

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

instead of

```
<!--saved from url=(0014)about:internet-->
```

Further the design of the HTMl was bad because the content was created via StringBuilder and the result was a long string, so there was no structure.
We have to use an array of type string instead of a StringBuilder and must write the array by the help of StreamWriter.
So this is the new code which works now:

```
List<string> htmlContent = new List<string>();

htmlContent.Add("<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->");
htmlContent.Add("<!DOCTYPE html>");
htmlContent.Add("<html lang=\"de\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">");
htmlContent.Add("<head>");
htmlContent.Add("<meta charset=\"utf-8\" content=\"IE=9\" />");
htmlContent.Add("<title></title>");
htmlContent.Add("</head>");
htmlContent.Add("<body>");
htmlContent.Add("<form>");
htmlContent.Add("<div id =\"pagecontent\">");
htmlContent.Add("<label>Wert 1</label><br/>");
htmlContent.Add("<input id =\"Wert1\" type=\"text\" maxlength=\"7\" placeholder=\"___,__\" title=\"Please use format ###,##\" pattern=\"^[+-]?\\d{0,3}((\\.|,)\\d{1,2})?\" style=\"font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; font-size:12px; text-align:left; height:20px; width:120px;\" /><br/>");
htmlContent.Add("<label>Wert 2</label><br/>");
htmlContent.Add("<input id =\"Wert2\" type=\"text\" maxlength=\"7\" placeholder=\"___,__\" title=\"Please use format ###,##\" pattern=\"^[+-]?\\d{0,3}((\\.|,)\\d{1,2})?\" style=\"font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; font-size:12px; text-align:left; height:20px; width:120px;\" /><br/>");
htmlContent.Add("<label>Ergebnis</label><br/>");
htmlContent.Add("<input id =\"Wert3\" readonly type=\"text\" disabled maxlength=\"7\" placeholder=\"___,__\" title=\"Please use format ###,##\" pattern=\"^[+-]?\\d{0,3}((\\.|,)\\d{1,2})?\" style=\"font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; font-size:12px; text-align:left; height:20px; width:120px;\" /><br/>");
htmlContent.Add("<script src =\"scripts/ValidationFunctions.js\"></script>");
htmlContent.Add("<script src =\"scripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js\"></script>");
htmlContent.Add("<script type =\"text/javascript\">");
htmlContent.Add("$(\"#pagecontent\").keyup(function () {CalculationTest();});");
htmlContent.Add("$(\"#pagecontent\").change(function () {CalculationTest();});");
htmlContent.Add("function CalculationTest() {var value_Z = parseFloat(ValidateNumberValue(document.getElementById(\"Wert1\").value.replace(\",\", \".\")));var value_RBMAX = parseFloat(ValidateNumberValue(document.getElementById(\"Wert2\").value.replace(\",\", \".\")));if (value_Z != 0 && value_RBMAX != 0) {document.getElementById(\"Wert3\").value = (value_Z*100/value_RBMAX).toFixed(2);} else {document.getElementById(\"Wert3\").value = null; }}");
htmlContent.Add("</script>");
htmlContent.Add("</div>");
htmlContent.Add("</form>");
htmlContent.Add("</body>");
htmlContent.Add("</html>");

string curDir = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string filePath = curDir + "\\calctest.html";
if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filePath);
System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8);
foreach (string htmlLine in htmlContent)
{
    sw.WriteLine(htmlLine);
}
sw.Close();

string pagePath = string.Format("file:///{0}/calctest.html", curDir).ToString();
wbcWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(pagePath));
```